Some of the ansible jobs having async tasks are failing without any error message in job output
Some of the ansible jobs having async tasks are failing without any error message in job output

FAILED - RETRYING: [server_fqdn]: wait for async job to end (660 retries left).

Tried to run the job but I was expecting a failure message for the job

It's not a failure - just a default message Ansible displays if the condition is not met yet while polling for the job status. The confusing wording itself has been an issue since 2017 at least but the maintainers decided they won't fix it as it could be done using a custom callback plugin.

Appreciate the comment above.
“job fails abruptly”, no error logs on the control or executor nodes. any area to look into ?

We can't help you without any example of code that you're trying to run.
